# How do 409a's and market caps compare?

Tags: market-capitalization, fair-value

I've found that MarketCap is a quick and decent way to evaluate a public company.  For private companies, the best I've found is a [409a](https://carta.com/blog/what-is-a-409a-valuation/).

It seems like, in many scenarios, both evaluation methods could be used for either company type.  If one were to evaluate a company using both the 409a method and market cap method, how would the two evaluations compare?  Would one almost always be larger?  Is one more accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 409A and the price someone is willing to pay for a private company are not the same.  A 409A for an early-stage business is usually performed immediately after a financing round.  This type of valuation is just a snapshot at that moment, which heavily discounts that an early-stage company can remain a going concern.  An investor looking to participate in a subsequent round of financing for a private company wouldn't typically refer to a past 409A due to the high likelihood that material events have transpired since the time at which that valuation was performed.  For an early-stage company, almost all events are material.

Most of the time private companies in this situation do not have earnings and are reliant upon financing.  A 409A valuation is most meaningful for employees of these companies who may need to report deferred compensation on their tax returns and need a share price in order to do so.

Investors considering companies that have profitability and the ability to forecast growth and cash flow will utilize different methods that are more forward-looking.